# Computing eigenfunction of expectational operator

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, operator-theory, eigenfunctions

Let $A$ be an operator from $\textbf{L}^2$ to itself defined by $$Af(x) = \mathbb{E}[e^{-W \gamma}\cdot f(x\cdot e^W)]$$ where $W$ is a $\mathbb{N}(0,1)$ distributed random variable and $\gamma \in [3,10]$ is a parameter. 
I believe there is no analytical method to compute the principal eigenfunction and eigenvalue of this operator.

By principal eigenfunction, I mean the positive function $f(x)$ such that $$Af(x) = \kappa f(x)$$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

What kind of numerical methods are used for problems of this sort?
Also, if anyone can recommend some textbook covering this kind of problems that would be amazing.

Thank you!

Edit: the source for this kind of problem is an Economics publication on long run risk exposure (Hansen and Scheinkman (2009))

Edit2: Uranix gave great tips to approach this specific problem but also made me realize that there is not much hope of solving this analytically in general (when the factor multiplying $f(x\cdot e^W)$ is a general function of $W$). Does anyone know which numerical techniques can be used in this context?

Comment: Please, add the missing parenthesis. I assume $Af(x) = \mathbb E[W^{-\gamma} f(x e^W) ]$ was meant instead. Also can you say something about $\gamma$ parameter?

Comment: Also, please clarify, what do you mean by principal eigenvalue. As the problem is formulated now, $f(x) = x^k$ is an eigenfunction, with positive eigenvalue when $k > 0$ and negative eigenvalue when $k < 0$ (assuming negative integer $\gamma$, otherwise eigenvalues are complex-valued)

Comment: Thanks Uranix for the comments, I modified the question. By principal eigenvalue I mean those which corresponds to a positive eigenfunction $f$. Gamma is a positive number between 3 and 10, sorry for not clarifying that earlier..)

Comment: A principal eigenvalue is usually the largest/the smallest eigenvalue of an operator. As I said, there are problems with negative $W$ when $\gamma > 0$.

Comment: You are spot on, I am sorry I made a mistake typing the operator... This is a special case of the general operator in which the $e^W$ is substituted by a general positive random variable but indeed the positivity is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a answer, but just some ideas.

So basically the operator in question acts as
$$
(Af)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-W\gamma} f(x e^W) e^{-W^2/2} dW
$$
Let $g(x) = (Af)(x)$ and let's split the $f$'s domain into three pieces:
$$
f(y) = \begin{cases}
f_{-}(y), &y < 0\\
f_0, & y = 0\\
f_{+}(y), &y > 0
\end{cases}
$$
One can easily see that $g_(x)$ is completely determined by $f_{-}(y)$, similarly $g_{+}(x)$ is determined by $f_{+}(y)$ and
$$
g_0 = f_0 e^{\gamma^2/2}.
$$
In other words, unless $f_0$ is zero, the eigenvalue should be equal to $e^{\gamma^2/2}$.

Assume that $f(y), \kappa$ is the principal eigenpair. It is necessary that
$$
(Af)(x) = \kappa f(x) 
$$ 
for $x > 0$. Also it is sufficient, since we can easily extend $f(x)$ is the following way (not the only possible):
$$
f_{-}(y) = f_{+}(y), \qquad f_0 = 0.
$$
So, assume now that $x > 0$, $f: \mathbb R_{+} \to \mathbb R$ and 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} f^2(y) dy < \infty.
$$
Introduce $s = x e^W > 0$. By changing variables,
$$
(Af)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{s}\right)^\gamma f(s) \exp\left(-\frac{(\log s - \log x)^2}{2}\right) \frac{ds}{s}
$$
which can be treated as an integral transform with kernel
$$
K(s,x) = \frac{x^\gamma}{\sqrt{2\pi}s^{\gamma+1}} \exp\left(-\frac{(\log s - \log x)^2}{2}\right)\\
(Af)(x) = \int_0^\infty K(s, x) f(s) ds.
$$
This kernel is a homogenous function:
$$
K(\lambda s, \lambda x) = \frac1\lambda K(s, x),\qquad \lambda > 0.
$$
Hence,
$$
(Af)(\lambda x) = \int_0^\infty K(s, \lambda x) f(s) ds = 
\int_0^{\infty} K(\lambda u, \lambda x) f(\lambda u) 
\lambda du = \int_0^\infty K(u, x) f(\lambda u) du = (Ah)(x)\\
h(u) \equiv f(\lambda u).
$$
If $f(x)$ is an eigenfunction, so is $h(x) = f(\lambda x)$, and they both have the same eigenvalue. Due to linearity of the transform, any linear combination also will be an eigenfunction. So should be
$$
k(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} p(\lambda) f(\lambda x) d\lambda
$$
for any integrable function $p(\lambda)$.

IDEA. Treat
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(\lambda x) p(\lambda) d\lambda = k(x) \equiv 1
$$
as an integral equation for $p(\lambda)$. If it has a solution, then $k(x) \equiv 1$ is an eigenfunction of the $A$ with same as $f(x)$ eigenvalue.

From now I strongly suspect that the only possible eigenfunction is $f(y) = \operatorname{const}$ with the eigenvalue equal to $e^{\gamma^2/2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this makes a lot of sense and is an approach I Would have not thought of, I'm trying to take it one step further at the moment.